# Fragment contains listview doesn't appear completely on my activity

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

This is my Activity.xml layout contains a fragment 
`enter code here`

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/txt_title"
            android:text="Chappie"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:background="#000"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"


            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Image_Poster"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/txt_release_date"
                    android:text="2015"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/txt_VoteAverage"
                    android:text="8.1/10"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#000"/>
                <RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:numStars="1"
                    android:stepSize="1.0"
                    android:rating="1.0"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#CDC5B4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/txt_overview"
            android:text="Every child comes into the world full of promise, and non more than Chappie:he is gifted, special, a prodigy. Chappie he is a robot."
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <fragment
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/TrailersFragment"
        android:name="com.example.prof_mohamed.movieapp.TrailersFragment"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

my Fragment layout trailers_fragment.xml file contains

`enter code here`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"    
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="14dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_trailers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"    />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="see Reviews"
        android:id="@+id/seeReviews"
        />
    </FrameLayout>
```

after inflating trailers_fragment.xml layout on my activity everything is running but my listview view its first item only and the remaining items disappears. can anybody tell me how to make my fragment responsive to the number of the listview items on my activity ? your response will be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: change the `ListView` height to `wrap_content`

Comment: this solution doesn't solve the problem, it still existing !

Comment: you can't use ListView inside ScrollView, that's your issue. You need to change your layout completely.

Answer (score 0):

You should use wrap_content or weight in your fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"    
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="14dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_trailers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="see Reviews"
        android:id="@+id/seeReviews"
        />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: no dear, this solution didn't optimize the problem. the problem is still existing !!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your original problem is something else. The ListView is inflating all the items, but only it's first item is visible to you and your not being able to scroll up to see the other items.

The issue is due to having a **Listview(In Fragment) inside a ScrollView**.

The ListView kept inside the ScrollView **does not stretch to its full height**. Plus, ListView implements its own ScrollListener. But here ListView  won't receive any scrolling gesture as it is handled by parent ScrollView.

Hence I would recommend you to remove your ScrollView and add the LinearLayout as a header of a ListView or find some other convenient solution

Thanks